# Is it possible to delete messages off a Samsung Galaxy remotely?

Tags: samsung, sms, remote-access, remote-wipe, samsung-messages

Can a Messages be wiped remotely off someone's Samsung phone?

My friend has been working at this place for a few years and recently had a pretty serious problem with his manager. He's continuing to work there, but the situation has gotten uncomfortable for him at work and thinks that he'll be fired as result. The friend at least figured if he got fired he'd have the messages to make a claim against his company if they fire him unfairly, until the other day when he discovered that his entire onversation history with his manager had been wiped off his phone.

His phone is a Samsung Galaxy A22 5G.

This friend of mine is not at all tech savvy (can't even figure out how to send screenshots to me (I know)) and I'm interstate, so I can't access the phone to help them. This manager it seems is more switched on than most, as they've already changed a bunch of access privelages on the computers at work. My friend insists that noone would have had access to their phone since they lost the messages, and is sure they've been deleted remotely. We figured out that the email account associated with the phone is the work email. To make things even worse, this friend is from a small town, and is unsure if people at the phone shop will know the manager or not, making taking it into someone risky.

I created a Samsung Cloud account to see if the message data could be edited or synced through a computer, but Messages was not listed as one of the apps. I don't have a Samsung to play around on so it's hard for me to help him, and I'm conscious that if I get him to play around with stuff it might do more harm than good. I need to be able to provide very clear instructions with pictures preferrably.

I'm sorry I can't post more information or the things that I've tried but it is hard for me to figure out what's happened remotely. If you need any extra information about the phone, let me know what you need and I can try communicate that to my friend. My main goal at this stage is to figure out if it's even possible to delete the messages in that way, and then to figure out how we'll get the messages back.

Thanks heaps in advance.